# Strategies for checking inactivity on Azure

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, azure-table-storage

I have a table in Azure Table Storage, with rows that are regularly updated by various processes. I want to efficiently monitor when rows *haven't* been updated within a specific time period, and to cause alerts to be generated if that occurs.

Most task scheduler implementations I've seen for Azure function by making sure only one worker will perform a given job at a time. However, setting up a scheduled task that waits *n* minutes, and then queries the latest time-stamp to determine if action should be taken, seems inefficient since the work won't be spread across workers. It also seems generally inefficient to have to poll so many records.

An example use of this would be to send an email to a user that hasn't logged into a web site in the last 30 days. Assume that the number of users is a "large number" for the purposes of producing an efficient algorithm.

Does anyone have any recommendations for strategies that could be used to check for recent activity without forcing only one worker to do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a LastActive table with a timestamp as a rowkey (`DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString("d19")`). Update it by doing a batch transaction that deletes the old row and inserts the new row.

Now the query for inactive users is just something like `from user in LastActive where user.PartitionKey == string.Empty && user.RowKey < (DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(30)).Ticks.ToString("d19") select user`. That will be quite efficient for any size table.

Depending on what you're going to do with that information, you might want to then put a message on a queue and then delete the row (so it doesn't get noticed again the next time you check). Multiple workers can now pull those queue messages and take action.

I'm confused about your desire to do this on multiple worker instances... you presumably want to act on an inactive user only once, so you want only one instance to do the check. (The work of sending emails or whatever else you're doing can then be spread about by using a queue, but that initial check should be done by exactly one instance.)

Comment: I used users as just a simplistic example. My data is actually being updated once every five second for each row. Updating an additional table would result in significantly more overhead than just table scanning through a few thousand rows. Ordinarily, you are also right that I can just queue the actual work to be done in order to avoid undue loading of a single worker. However, given that the queues are limited to ~500 messages/sec, working on let's say, 5000 rows will take 50 seconds to queue. I was hoping to somehow process directly.

Comment: More importantly, by putting all of these rows in the same PK, I'd also be limiting the number of updates/sec I can do to 500. I'd like to be scalable into the thousands.

Comment: If the scan is faster, then I guess I don't understand what you're asking. Do the scan. If one partition isn't scalable enough, use multiple partitions. If one queue isn't scalable enough, use multiple queues. If you're bumping into limits on the entire storage account, you could use multiple storage accounts, or you might want to consider a different storage technology.